# Change json data to Typescript interface objects in Angular 2

Tags: json, object, dictionary, typescript, angular

I have json data that is structured like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1467471622,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 3.673027,
    "AFN": 68.475,
    "ALL": 123.095199,
    "AMD": 476.8075,
    "ANG": 1.78385,
    "AOA": 165.846832,
    "ARS": 15.05143,
    "AUD": 1.333463,
    "AWG": 1.793333,
    "AZN": 1.553975,
    "BAM": 1.757679,
    "BBD": 2,
    "BDT": 78.33184,
    "BGN": 1.756683,
    "BHD": 0.377337,
    "BIF": 1660.642515,
    "BMD": 1,
    "BND": 1.344589,
```

How can I map this to muliple objects in typescript like this:

```
export interface Stock {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The json data doesn't have the stock name in it and by value do you just want the price in USD? What I would do is write some interfaces that represent the json data's structure, then write some interfaces for how I want to use the data in the application, then write some code to map the data between them.

Comment: Actually, this data seems to represent currency exchange rates. I see that `base` is USD and at the moment 1 USD ≈ 1.33 AUD. Might not be good to call it `Stock` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let keys = Object.keys(data.rates);
let mapped: Stock[] = keys.map(key => {
    return { name:key, value: data.rates[key] } as Stock
});

console.log(mapped);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qfo43o24

Answer (score 1):

You donot need to map manually. Your Typescript code can be:

```
export interface Stock{
  timestamp : Number,
  base : String,
  rates : Rates
}

export class Rates{
  AED : Number,
 ..... so on
```